# I have found this problem failed to get away from me

Tags: ide, cs50

```
~/pset1/mario/ $ make mario
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    mario.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o mario
mario.c:6:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: mario] Error 1
~/pset1/mario/ $
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message means you are missing a bracket ")" or "(" in line 6 of your source code.

`mario.c:6:1:`  refers to the address or the location of the error.

Comment: Thank you very much finally i sorted it out.

Comment: no problem. glad to be of help.